# template template parameter specialiation in nested classes

Tags: c++, templates

I encountered such a problem:

I have a class which takes a template class as:

```
template<typename N, template<typename> T > A : SomeLibClass<T<N>>
```

Then I actually have another class as say:

```
template<typename T, unsigned count = 1> B
```

In a third class I wants to do essentially like this:

```
template<typename N, unsigned count = 1> C
{
    template<typename T> class SpecialB : public B<T, count> {}

    A<N, SpecialB> someClassLevelVar;
}
```

Then I got a problem in dynamic casting from the compiler, saying cannot cast from `A<N, SpecialB>` to `A<N, B<T, 1>>`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: And actual C++ code! How can you expect us to identify issues if you just give us pseudofragments?

Comment: Right. Just didn't have time to post such a MCVE. Will do it soon.